# browser.Eval() throwing Exception

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, watin

I want to enter text in a textfield using c# Watin. I am using the following statement to do the same

```
browser.Eval(string.Format("$('#{0}').val('design')","searchQuery"));
```

but it is giving me the following exception:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined in browser.Eval()

Comment: The error means that jQuery is not included in the page. You need to add a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have jQuery added as part of your application, then you can go with the traditional java script.

```
string query = "var e=document.getElementById('{0}');e.value='{1}'";
browser.Eval(string.Format(query, "searchQuery", "design"));
```